# Excel:- How to count the number of times data in a range crosses a value

Tags: excel, countif

I am struggling with COUNTIF trying to count the number of times data within a column crosses a specific value.   A search on the forum has revealed how I can count the number of values in the data set that lie within a tolerance of the specific value, but that is not what I want because I only want to count it if the next value crosses over.   Is there an easy way to do this in Excel?
Sorry if this is not clear enough - this is my first post to the forum.
Thanks for any help,
Finlay

Comment: What do you mean by "crosses over" ? please post some example of your data, and of the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is vague, so will this answer be...

1. You'll need to add a column that checks to see if the number meets your criteria.
2. Do a count if based on this new column.

If you add more details to your question, I can expand the answer more.